# The asymptotic behaviour of the Fourier transform of a certain class of radially symmetric functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Fix $\theta\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and let $a>0$. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic in $S:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |\arg{z}|<\pi/2\}$ and
$$|f(z)|\sim |z|^{-a},\qquad |z|\to \infty,\qquad z\in S.$$
Let $g(x):=f(e^{i \theta} x)$. Then $x\mapsto g(|x|)$ is obviously continuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and consequently has a Fourier transform in the sense of tempered distributions.

Is it true that

$$|\mathcal{F}\left(g(|\cdot|)\right)(\xi)|\sim |\xi|^{a-d},\qquad \text{as}\quad |\xi|\to 0$$

Comment: There are no such functions $f$: a  bounded entire function is constant.

Comment: I corrected the question. Sorry about the multiple edits.